# Flask render_template not returning the correct file

Tags: python, flask

I have been coding a flask app that works perfectly fine while running locally, but while hosting the app a strange bug occurs. After I've posted a string to the server it responds with the expected page, but when I repeat it with another request (without restarting the server) the same page as earlier is displayed yet again.

It seems like the render_template does not update the changes I've done in the HTML file after it already has rendered the template, even though the command is run again.

```
@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        content = str(request.form['content'])

        # Some code that changes the "output.html" page based on the user input

        return render_template('output.html')
  
    else:
        return render_template("index.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use redirect instead of render_template in your `if` condition, like this:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = str(request.form['content'])
        return redirect(url_for('output.html'))
    else:
        return render_template("index.html")
```

Comment: It is a good idea, but it doesn't solve the core problem. The page redirected to still need to render_template the "output.html"

Comment: Of course i expect him to have an endpoint for `output.html'

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Apparently the page doesn't update if it has the same URL as before even though a new template is rendered under the same URL. The solution was to make a dynamic URL.